# Reputation changes are not visible on the profile page

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

Yesterday, I had 899 reputation and now I have 895 reputation, which means that I lost 4 reputation since yesterday. However, in the reputation tab on my profile, it only says that I lost 2 reputation since yesterday:

[image: screenshot]

Where did the 2 other reputation go? Why isn't this change visible on my profile page?

Comment: Do you have "show removed posts" checked?

Comment: I checked it and then I could see that I lost 4 reputation and for the other -2 it said "removed". But why did I lose reputation because a post was removed and why isn't this visible without checking "show removed posts"?

Comment: You probably lost +2 from a suggested edit to a now-deleted post.  As for the UI design of the "show removed post" I don't know the design decision behind that.